# How to search and replace url using .htaccess (regex)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Below is the code from my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Below is what I want to search and replace:

1. `https://example.com/video-17i8mp51/27628401/0/ok-ask-me-right`
   to
   `https://example.com/video-17i8mp51/ok-ask-me-right`
2. `https://example.com/search/full+movie?top&id=57448561`
   to
   `https://example.com/search/full+movie`
3. This URL is in over 10k of my site content's
   `https://anothersiteurl.com/search/full+movie`
   to
   `https://mysiteurl.com/search/full+movie`

Comment: "3 This url is in over 10k of my site content's" - This isn't something you should be modifying with `.htaccess`. #1 and #2 look like two static redirects - is that the case? What have you tried?

Comment: I fail to see _any_ attempt in that file to rewrite requests according to what you write that you want to achieve ...

Comment: @MrWhite I totally do not know where to start from, please help in any way you can!

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any "search and replace" here? You seem to be just redirecting from one URL to another - is that correct?

Comment: @MrWhite yes "redirecting from one URL to another"

Comment: @MrWhite am still waiting for your answer please.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming these are static one-to-one redirects, as seemingly confirmed in comments.

Both the following rules should go *after* the first rule (the canonical HTTP to HTTPS and www to non-www redirect) and *before* the front-controller pattern.

> 1. `https://example.com/video-17i8mp51/27628401/0/ok-ask-me-right`
>    to
>    `https://example.com/video-17i8mp51/ok-ask-me-right`

```
RewriteRule ^(video-17i8mp51)/27628401/0/(ok-ask-me-right)$ /$1/$2 [R=302,L]
```

Where the `$1` and `$2` backreferences contain the captured subgroups from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. `video-17i8mp51` and `ok-ask-me-right` respectively. This simply saves repetition in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string.

> 2. `https://example.com/search/full+movie?top&id=57448561`
>    to
>    `https://example.com/search/full+movie`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^top&id=57448561$
RewriteRule ^search/full\+movie$ /$0 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The `$0` backreference contains the full match of the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `search/full_movie`). Note that the literal `+` needs to be backslash escaped in the regex to negate it's special meaning in the regex.

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag removes the original query string from the redirect response.

You should not repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive.

Note that these are currently 302 (temporary) redirects. If these are intended to be permanent then change to 301 but only after you have tested that they work as intended, to avoid potential caching issues.

> 3. This url is in over 10k of my site content's
>    `https://anothersiteurl.com/search/full+movie`
>    to
>    `https://mysiteurl.com/search/full+movie`

This is not something you should be trying to do with `.htaccess`. If this URL appears in the site "content" then you need to modify the content of your pages before sending the response.

(Technically, you can use mod_substitute to do this - to modify the response body - but really that would be a last resort.)

---

*Aside:* The `RewriteBase` directive is not being used here and can therefore be removed.

---

#### Summary

Your resulting `.htaccess` file would then look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Canonical redirect (HTTP to HTTPS and www to non-www)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

# Point#1
RewriteRule ^(video-17i8mp51)/27628401/0/(ok-ask-me-right)$ /$1/$2 [R=302,L]

# Point#2
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^top&id=57448561$
RewriteRule ^search/full\+movie$ /$0 [QSD,R=302,L]

# Front-controller pattern
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^top&id=57448561$
RewriteRule ^search/full\+movie$ /$0 [QSD,R=302,L]`   @MrWhite you do focus only on example URL, I want generally do this in all url containing `?top&id=numbers`

Comment: @ZamaniVogue Because your examples are static, single URLs - you've not stated what the variable parts are. The question simply asks how to redirect from one URL to the other. I tried to seek clarification in comments, and you simply repeated my question that you are "redirecting from one URL to another". You need to state which parts in the URLs are variable and _how_ they are variable, ie. containing only numbers, letters, etc. Please update your question with the additional information, otherwise we are _guessing_ what your intentions are.

Comment: @ZamaniVogue In the 2nd example (the one quoted in your comment), there was no indication that the URL-path (ie. `/search/full+movie`) was variable. Is it `/search/<movie-name>` or literally `/<anything>`? Is `video-17i8mp51` (1st example) also variable? Is it `video-<digits-and-lowercase-letters>`? Is the last path segment (ie. `ok-ask-me-right`) in that example also variable? If so, what characters can it contain? Or is it a specific _video URL_ you are wanting to redirect? You need to be specific.

Comment: I want to generally redirect all the url containing `&id=anynumbers`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to meet all three of your criteria with the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# First request:
# Convert https://example.com/video-17i8mp51/27628401/0/ok-ask-me-right to
#         https://example.com/video-17i8mp51/ok-ask-me-right
RewriteRule ^(video-[^/]+)/.+/(.+)/?$ $1/$2 [L]

# Second request:
# Convert https://example.com/search/full+movie?top&id=57448561 to
#         https://example.com/search/full+movie
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?

# Third request:
# Convert https://anothersiteurl.com/search/full+movie to
#         https://mysiteurl.com/search/full+movie
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysiteurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can see them in action [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=68a4a9ed-c8db-4fc5-9815-93252a98f0da).